# My basic if statement doesn't work in a Flask template

Tags: python, if-statement, flask

I am learning flask, and my basic if statement does not work properly
here's the flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="template")

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")

def hello_world():
    name = "Ana de Armas"
    return render_template('index.html', title='wekcine', username=name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello_world()
```

and here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if username == "Ana de Armas": %}
        <h1>Hello my love</h1>
    {% else %}
        <h1>Hello {{ username }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to practice if statements on flask and my basic if statement didn't even worked properly hope you can help me.

Comment: `if username == "Ana de Armas":` You don't need the colon at the end.  I assume that is the problem.

Comment: In the `else` block, what does `Hello {{ username }}` show?

Comment: In the future, instead of just saying "doesn't work properly", specify _exactly_ what it does that's improper. Throws an exception? Then the exception should be part of your question's text.

Comment: so, what I get as an output even I have the username "Ana de Armas" is just Hello Ana de Armas so I guess the else block works fine (when I try other usernames it outputs correctly)? So, the first statement doesn't work, also I tried to remove the colon ":" at the end of my first if statement still didn't work. And sorry for the lack of details in my question, I will surely avoid them in my future questions.

Answer (score 0):

remove the colon from the end of the if statement

`{% if username == "Ana de Armas": %}`
should be
`{% if username == "Ana de Armas" %}`

Comment: so, what I get as an output even I have the username "Ana de Armas" is just Hello Ana de Armas so I guess the else block works fine (when I try other usernames it outputs correctly)? So, the first statement doesn't work, also I tried to remove the colon ":" at the end of my first if statement still didn't work.

Comment: Im not sure why this is happening. All I can suggest is debugging using things such as <p> {{username}} </p>